# Showing google trends graphs in web browser control

Tags: google-trends

I have added the following code to display google trends TIMESERIES graph in my windows application using web browser control. It is working fine for some time. After some hits, it showing 'You have reached your limit." and not showing any graphs. 
WebBrowser1.DocumentText=< body>" & "document.write('http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?hl\75en-AU\46q\75samsung\46content\0751\46cid\75TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0\46export\0755\46w\075500\46h\075330"" style=""border: none;"">');" & "< /body>"

Please let me know how to resolve this limitation issue.